# How can I return the file path using the JNLP file chooser

Tags: java, swing, jnlp

Hi I am trying to get the returned file path by my JNLP file chooser. Here's my code.
I don't know how and where to get the file path. is it from fileContents? fileConents.getfilepath something like that?

```
try {

        if (fileOpenService==null) {
            fileOpenService = (FileOpenService)ServiceManager.
                lookup("javax.jnlp.FileOpenService");
        }
        fileContents = fileOpenService.openFileDialog(path, xtns);

    } catch(UnavailableServiceException use) {
        use.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It may not be possible, but I'd check [FileContents#getName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/FileContents.html) and see what it returns

Comment: unfortunately it returns the file name... not the file path. :(

Comment: perhaps you can get the file path of that file name instead?

Comment: You can access the content, as shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/usingJNLPAPI.html).

Answer (score 0):

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

> You can call other methods on the File object, such as
>   getPath, isDirectory, or exists to obtain information about the file.
>   You can also call other methods such as delete and rename to change
>   the file in some way. Of course, you might also want to open or save
>   the file by using one of the reader or writer classes provided by the
>   Java platform. See Basic I/O for information about using readers and
>   writers to read and write data to the file system.

Answer (score 0):

It is for security reasons that a `FileContents` will not return a path.  The JRE asked the user if our app. could access the content of that file, not it's path.

It is a bit like the brower/HTML based file upload field.  Some browsers provide the entire path, while more typically it is just the content/name.